# MacVim erases file color labels

Tags: macos, macvim

This might be more suited for apple.SE, but here is my question anyway.

When editing with MacVim a file that has a color label, the color label disappears when the file is saved.
I have the feeling that this is because vim uses a temporary file (the buffer), and replaces the original file with the buffer... But please correct me if I'm wrong.

Is this normal? Is this a bug I should report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include `set nowritebackup` and `set nobackup`  in your `.vimrc`/`.gvimrc`.

`:help writebackup`

```
'writebackup' 'wb'  boolean (default on with |+writebackup| feature, off
                    otherwise)
            global
            {not in Vi}
    Make a backup before overwriting a file.  The backup is removed after
    the file was successfully written, unless the 'backup' option is
    also on.  Reset this option if your file system is almost full.  See
    |backup-table| for another explanation.
    When the 'backupskip' pattern matches, a backup is not made anyway.
    NOTE: This option is set to the default value when 'compatible' is
    set.
```